# Most efficient way to solve this circular reference?

Tags: c#, oop, visual-studio-2013, circular-dependency

New to C# here. So I got my first class (Form1) and second class (Class1) in different projects. I added Form1 to Class1's references because Form1 had data from its GUI that Class1 needed to make computations from its method. Problem is, I cant get the results from the method in Class1 to Form1 because I can't reference it because of circular reference.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // for getting data from Class1
       // ClassLibrary1.Class1 c = new ClassLibrary1.Class1();
       // label7.Text = c.GetDate();        }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}



 public class Class1
 {

    private int daysz;

    private int GetDate()
    {
        Activity3_Espiritu.Form1 f = new Activity3_Espiritu.Form1();
        daysz = (f.lastDay - f.firstDay).Days;
        return daysz;
    }

}
```

What's a clean way to get around this? I've tried interfaces but I've absolutely no idea how to use it, even after looking online for solutions.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a good question for this site (next time better try https://programmers.stackexchange.com), but the usual way to avoid circular references in this form would be to introduce a new type which both of the old types reference.

Comment: Pass the necessary data to class1 and get the result back. don't reference form1 in class1

Comment: Where are `lastDay` and `firstDay` declared? They are not in the Form or in the Class1.  If they're in the form, then you don't need Class1 to calculate the length of the date range at all, you just need to pass the length to Class1 (if you want to store it there)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class1 should never need a reference to your Form1, instead the code from Form1 should call the `GetDate()` method in Class1 and pass in the appropriate parameters for `GetDate()` to evaluate. When `GetDate()` returns the result you simply assign it to a variable or back into the user control that needs to show it (would that be `Label7`?).

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var c = new Class1();
    var yourResult = c.GetDate(lastDay, firstDay);
    label7.Text = yourResult;
}

public int GetDate(DateTime lastDate, DateTime firstDate)
{
    return (lastDate - firstDate).Days;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can change signature of `GetDate` method you can try this code:

```
public class Class1
{
  private int daysz;

  private int GetDate(__yourDatType__ lastDay, __yourDatType__ firstDay)
  {
    daysz = (lastDay - firstDay).Days;
    return daysz;
  }
}
```

now, in  `button1_Click` write this:

```
ClassLibrary1.Class1 c = new ClassLibrary1.Class1();
label7.Text = c.GetDate(this.lastDay, this.firstDay);
```